# Однозначные слова

Tags: семантика

Как найти в толковом словаре три однозначных слова?

Comment: Танечка, а слабо самой делать домашние задания? Так ведь ничему и не научитесь.

Answer (score 2):

Сосна - и дерево, и древесина этого дерева (собирательное). В этом лесу - одна сосна (о сосновон лесе).

Лошадь - и животное, и характеристика человека, обладающего какими-либо качествами, свойственными такому животному.

Яма - не только углубление в земле. Яма в стене, ямы ключиц. Водяная яма - омут. Воздушная яма - разреженное пространство в воздухе, где самолёт резко снижается, как бы проваливается). Раньше ямой называли тюрьму.

Однозначное слово - синхрофазотрон. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Однозначные слова имеют в русском языке только одно значение.
Например: *сосна, лошадь, яма*.

Answer (score 0):

Ищи какие-нибудь сложные технические (и не только) термины. Точно не ошибёшься. Полностью согласен с предыдущим ответом.

Comment: Не стоит писать "предыдущий ответ". Расположение ответов может изменяться, как и произошло здесь.

Comment: Хорошо-хорошо. Учту ;-)